# Send Data Request as String in C# to comms port

Tags: c#, communication

I need to send a write method as a string in C# to a com port. It should be enclosed btween stx and etx.

e.g. serialPort1.write("02TY000D03") - where the 02 and 03 are stx and etx.

Could someone provide a quick example please as I don't think the code above is correct?

Many thanks

Darren.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use escape codes;

```
serialPort1.Write("\x02TY000D\x03");
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a sample I took from [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/coad/archive/2005/03/23/SerialPort-_2800_RS_2D00_232-Serial-COM-Port_2900_-in-C_2300_-.NET.aspx):

```
// This is a new namespace in .NET 2.0
// that contains the SerialPort class 
using System.IO.Ports; 

private static void SendSampleData() { 
    // Instantiate the communications
    // port with some basic settings 
    SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One); 

    // Open the port for 
    communications port.Open(); 

    // Write a string 
    port.Write("Hello World"); 

    // Write a set of bytes 
    port.Write(new byte[] {0x0A, 0xE2, 0xFF}, 0, 3); 

    // Close the port 
    port.Close();
}
```

Therefore you may be better using Write instead of write, note the capital W. If 02 and 03 are byte values you will have to escape the values with `\x`, i.e. `\x03`;